# Union type with empty array resolves to never[]

Tags: typescript

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXig4AnAlgOwOYDaAugFAm7AQYBmcAxtAGID2zUA3lGBs2AFyxE0AL5kKVWg0EYOXHv0FIookqEhQWzeDNSaoAH2lk6zHOiiV0Azdqip2JKE7m8BxEisvAAdN15A)

```
type Base = string[]

interface Foo { prop: Base }

interface Bar { prop: Base }

type FooBar = Foo | Bar

const test: FooBar = {
    prop: [] // property prop resolves to never[] here
}

test.prop // property prop resolves to Base here
```

Why is the type in cost declaration resolved to `never[]` and not `Base` since the definitions in both `Foo` and `Bar` of property `prop` are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Because `test` is not `{prop: []}`, it's `FooBar`

```
const test: FooBar = {
    prop: [] // property prop resolves to never[] here
}
// is same as: 
const test2 = {prop:[]} as FooBar; // type is lost
```

What you want is

```
const test = {
    prop: []
} satisfies FooBar
```

and `satisfies` is `ts@>=4.9`

Comment: Test is `FooBar` but `prop` should be `Base` type instead of `never` when test is declared. When accessed via `test.prop` it is of `Base` type. Why does prop inside of test gets resolved to never?

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be, that you've used two unions `Foo | Bar` which are not discriminated. If you define a **discriminant property** in each of them, this problem will be solved.

Change `Foo` and `Bar` like this(`kind` is a discriminant property):

```
interface Foo { 
    prop: Base;
    kind: 'Foo' 
}

interface Bar { 
    prop: Base;
    kind: 'Bar' 
}
```

And during the `test` definition:

```
const test: FooBar = {
    prop: [], // property prop is never[] no more, it is Base type.
    kind:"Bar"
}
```

For more information about discriminated unions pay attention to [this article](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions#discriminated-union).